# Where is my BIOS chip? (Image)

Tags: motherboard, bios, firmware, flashing

**I'm trying to flash my Toshiba Satellite C660-1ZM with a self compiled BIOS update, however I can't seem to locate the chip.**

Solutions tried:

1. Looking at the motherboard schematic: I can't find any parameters
   that match what I'm looking for.
2. Looking at the components under a magnifying lens: nothing comes up
   in search engine results.

I've attached pictures of the motherboard below.

[Here is the PDF file of the schematic](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/motherboard/compal/compal_la-7202p_r1.0_schematics.pdf)

[Close up of U13 (with etching visible)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt5Gd.jpg)

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Comment: This is a hardware question... and calls for *considerable* skill *and* equipment to resolder these micro-components. Have you ever done anything like this before?

Comment: It *could* be U13 on page 15, but given the low size of the images there is no way for us to say where that chip is. As mentioned this requires some skill not to cause serious damage.

Comment: Well, yes. It’s the SPI flash memory. However, you may not be able to program this chip in-system.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies, I won't be desoldering these, instead bridging them via some clips. I'll try updating the question with some higher resolution pictures.

Comment: Image of U13 has been updated with higher resolution.

Comment: It is usually in close proximity to the cmos battery.

Comment: @Mokubai is on the right track.  U13 is a SPI NOR flash chip.  The block diagram diagram refers to it as *"ROM"*, but that seems to be a misnomer to just differentiate it from RAM.  Note that NOR flash is capable of execute-in-place (XIP), which is a nice feature for a BIOS chip, but an added-cost and useless capability when the flash is used for simply data storage (e.g. use NAND instead).

Comment: @AN1 *"bridging them via some clips"* -- Why?  What makes you think that you can interface this chip while it is still soldered, i.e. in circuit?  The chip is probably an 8-pin SOIC package.  Do you have a SOIC test clip?

Comment: @sawdust Yes, I have a 8-pin SOIC test clip connected to a PC via USB programmer.

Comment: @Mokubai Do you mind taking a look at this datasheet for chip at U13: [link](https://www.mxic.com.tw/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/7355/MX25L3206E,%203V,%2032Mb,%20v1.5.pdf)

Comment: @AN1 what about it? The original motherboard sheet you provided was quite clear about the pinout.